# swift filter array produces duplicates (How to remove filter duplicates)

Tags: arrays, swift, date, struct, filter

I've created a filtered messages by dates with data retrieved from Firebase Database. My goal is to make header sections for corresponding message groups.

```swift
struct dateModelStructure {
        var date: String
        var contents: String
    }
var messagesPerDateDictionary: [dateModelStructure] = []
var dateSection = [Any]()
```

```swift
var array = [Any]()
array = self.messagesPerDateDictionary.filter { $0.date == chat.datestampString()}
self.dateSection.append(array)
```

The problem is if I append the array to dateSection, it appends the whole duplicate data. For example,

```
[
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?")], 
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Um...my chat..where did it go?")], 
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Um...my chat..where did it go?"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Thank you")], 
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_images%2FDF89F565-9BDB-442F-83B4-B5D6E0BD0739?alt=media&token=9d54f505-50ce-45f5-999e-2d7c6981ec20")], 
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_images%2FDF89F565-9BDB-442F-83B4-B5D6E0BD0739?alt=media&token=9d54f505-50ce-45f5-999e-2d7c6981ec20"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_movies%2F155A8712-F437-4B3E-AE76-97ECA1C3A4B6.mov?alt=media&token=a12c4f7f-d46a-4109-ace0-97bdacaf04cf")], 
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-15", contents: "Counts")]
]
```

What could I do if I just wanted something like this.

```
[ 
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Um...my chat..where did it go?"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Thank you")],  
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_images%2FDF89F565-9BDB-442F-83B4-B5D6E0BD0739?alt=media&token=9d54f505-50ce-45f5-999e-2d7c6981ec20"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_movies%2F155A8712-F437-4B3E-AE76-97ECA1C3A4B6.mov?alt=media&token=a12c4f7f-d46a-4109-ace0-97bdacaf04cf")], 
[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-15", contents: "Counts")]
]
```

I apologize if I haven't made my question clear enough.
Thank you for you help!

Comment: let arrayUnordered = Array(Set(array))

Comment: let arrayOrdered = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: array))

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem is not with `filter`. It seems like you're doing the filter as the `messagesPerDateDictionary` gets appended with new stuff. Performing the filter once your dictionary has all the contents should solve your issue

Comment: This looks a bit unfinished to me. If you consider to have a chat with a firebase connection, you might want to use timestamps instead of just `YYYY-MM-DD`. How are you filter for different conversations on the same day? Also its totaly fine that `filter` produces duplicates because it just filters with the given requirement.

Comment: @zero3nna You are right. I will sort with timestamps as I figure out how to remove all the duplicates in my array :)

Comment: @LokSN You were correct. I found out that messagesPerDateDictionary already had those duplicates. I'm now trying to deal with messagesPerDateDictionary :) Thank you

Comment: @chicshinshin anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up in playground. I hope I understood your question right:

```
class ChatViewController {

    struct dateModelStructure: Hashable {
        var date: String
        var contents: String

        static func ==(lhs: ChatViewController.dateModelStructure, rhs: ChatViewController.dateModelStructure) -> Bool {
            return lhs.date == rhs.date && lhs.contents == rhs.contents
        }
    }

    var messagesPerDateDictionary: [dateModelStructure] = []
    var dateSection = [Any]()
}

var someData = [
    [ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?")],
    [ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?"),ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Um...my chat..where did it go?")],
    [ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Um...my chat..where did it go?"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Thank you")],
    [ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_images%2FDF89F565-9BDB-442F-83B4-B5D6E0BD0739?alt=media&token=9d54f505-50ce-45f5-999e-2d7c6981ec20")],
    [ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_images%2FDF89F565-9BDB-442F-83B4-B5D6E0BD0739?alt=media&token=9d54f505-50ce-45f5-999e-2d7c6981ec20"), ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_movies%2F155A8712-F437-4B3E-AE76-97ECA1C3A4B6.mov?alt=media&token=a12c4f7f-d46a-4109-ace0-97bdacaf04cf")],
    [ChatViewController.dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-15", contents: "Counts")]
]

var helperDict = [String: [ChatViewController.dateModelStructure]]()

someData.forEach { (data) in
    guard let firstDate = data.first?.date else {
        return
    }
    if let existingArray = helperDict[firstDate] {
        helperDict[firstDate] = existingArray + data
    } else {
        helperDict[firstDate] = data
    }
}

var filtered : [[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure]] = helperDict.values.reduce([[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure]]()) { (previous, current) -> [[ChatViewController.dateModelStructure]] in
    var next = [Array(Set(current))] + previous
    return next
}



filtered.forEach { (items) in
    print ("------------------------------")
    items.forEach({ (item) in
        print(item)
    })
}

------------------------------
dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_images%2FDF89F565-9BDB-442F-83B4-B5D6E0BD0739?alt=media&token=9d54f505-50ce-45f5-999e-2d7c6981ec20")
dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-14", contents: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tikitalka-a8e51.appspot.com/o/message_movies%2F155A8712-F437-4B3E-AE76-97ECA1C3A4B6.mov?alt=media&token=a12c4f7f-d46a-4109-ace0-97bdacaf04cf")
------------------------------
dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Why did you call me a fat cat?")
dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Um...my chat..where did it go?")
dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-13", contents: "Thank you")
------------------------------
dateModelStructure(date: "2019-08-15", contents: "Counts")
```

This code can be improved but let me know if it giving you the result you were searching for.